# Spatial join of polygon to point not transferring attributes in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-join

What I have:

- 1 point layer with adresses.
- 1 polygon layer with zones.

[image: Points and polygons]

What I want: 1 point layer with the polygon info added.

I just did the spatial join, the columns are added but there's no info joined. Everything is NULL. 
I Googled and there seemed to be a bug, but that was for ArcMap 10 and I have 10.3. I can't find any patches nor servicepacks.

What am I missing here?

Comment: does it work if you right click on the point > join > join based on spatial location ? Have you checked your coordinate systems ? What option of spatial join did you use ?

Comment: Can you confirm your Target and Join  feature classes were correct and that join operation was set to "one to many", not the "one to one" default, and match option "intersect"? I've encountered some strange behaviour regarding dissapearing attributes in 10.3 myself. When copying and pasting from one layer to another with the same field structure, attributes are nullified in 10.3.  Not sure if this is related but there may be a bug...

Comment: radouxju, It was the projection after all. Very small difference but it was a difference...arghl. A mistake I'm never making again! Thanks for the quick responses radouxju and Jakub!

Comment: Please check your coordinate systems.

Answer (score -2):

SHP with adresses (points) was in a different coordinate sytem as the polygon SHP.

Point SHP:

> Geographic Coordinate System: **GCS_Belge_1972**
>   Datum:    D_Belge_1972
>   Prime Meridian:   Greenwich
>   Angular Unit:     Degree

Polygon SHP:

> Projected Coordinate System:  **Belge_Lambert_1972**
>   Projection:   Lambert_Conformal_Conic
>   False_Easting:    150000,01256000
>   False_Northing:   5400088,43780000
>   Central_Meridian: 4,36748667
>   Standard_Parallel_1:  49,83333390
>   Standard_Parallel_2:  51,16666723
>   Latitude_Of_Origin:   90,00000000
>   Linear Unit:  Meter
>
> Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_Belge_1972
>   Datum:    D_Belge_1972
>   Prime Meridian:   Greenwich
>   Angular Unit:     Degree

So with the ArcToolbox > Projections and Transformations > Define Projection I added the Belge_Lambert_1972 to the Point SHP.

Comment: -1. They were not in different systems. Projection for Point shapefile was wrong or undefined.