# Polygon data to Point Feature Data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon, point

Using ArcGis 10.0. What I am looking for is a way to get point features that are placed in a polygon to have the same "Address" value.

This is the same as the "Spatial Join" feature, however, I am only trying to extract one field not all the fields in the polygon layer.

Is there a way to "Spatial Join" from a polygon to a point feature while selecting what fields from the polygon you wish to keep?

Comment: see the similar question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158168/arcgis-10-3-spatial-join-polygon-to-point

Comment: Stephen Lead, I have adjusted the question to be a bit clearer to what I require.

Comment: Use polygon layer property and hide unwanted fields. Spatial join output will have only visible fields

Comment: Thanks FelixIP, I am currently doing this but wanted to know if there was a way to get rid of any unwanted information.

Comment: @Caleb add @ sign before user name if you want him/her to hear you

Comment: @Caleb I voted to reopen your post because post mentioned as answering it has nothing to do with your issue

Comment: The duplicate currently used is about converting polygons to centroids and/or vertices, so I agree with @FelixIP that this should be re-opened.  The history of the question is a bit hard to follow in its timeline but at one time it was vague enough for the duplicate to have been reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

@Caleb if you use the Spatial Join (Analysis) tool, you can click on fields that pop up in the 'Field Map of Join Features (optional)' portion of the tool window.  While a field is highlighted, click on the 'X' to the right and it will delete from view (and therefor not show up in your Join output feature class).  Also, you can set join rules for certain fields by clicking the '+' to the right while a certain field is highlighted.  Make sure you pay attention to which Match Option you select, I suggest reading about the COMPLETELY_CONTAINS option and see if it matches your needs.

Hope that helps.  I should also note that I am using ArcGIS v. 10.3.